# Specify upload path using swfupload

Tags: php, swfupload

I'm using SwfUpload and I want to be able to specify the destination folder. Right now I have hard coded the final destination, but I would like to be able to control it on the fly. Is there a way to get SwfUpload to submit it to my upload script? I tried adding it as a hidden variable to the form that displays the uploader, but it doesn't make it to my script:

Here's the form that shows the uploader. The rest of the page is pretty standard so I didn't include it.  Look for the hidden field "destinationpath"

```
<form id="form1" action="nowhere.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Select file to upload for program.
    </p>

        <div class="fieldset flash" id="fsUploadProgress">
        <span class="legend">Upload Queue</span>
        </div>
    <div id="divStatus">0 Files Uploaded</div>
        <div>
            <span id="spanButtonPlaceHolder"></span>
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel All Uploads" onclick="swfu.cancelQueue();" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 2px; font-size: 8pt; height: 29px;" />
        </div>
    <input name="destinationpath" type="hidden" value="c:/DigitalMediaFiles/">
</form>
```

Then in upload.php I check for it:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["destinationpath"]))
    $save_path  = $_REQUEST["destinationpath"];
```

but its not set. I suspect that swf upload does not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to specify the parameter in post_params of the SWFSettings object

post_params: 
                    {
                     "destinationpath" : "C:\DigitalMediaFiles"
                    },

I tried using addPostParam() but that did not work for me. putting it in post_params of the settings did.

Answer (score 0):

If your destination folder is not related to the up-loader(client), you can do it in your php script, without getting that variables from client side scripts. That is save the file in your target directory by php script.

If the destination folder is different from each client, still you can save them in a same directory and use your .htaccess file to rewrite urls for each client(using client id). In this case you need to save your file that keeps client id in a portion of the file name. You can explode file name by using a delimiter.

If still you need to do it your own way that is you mentioned in your question,just use post_params: {} function in your configuration js file which is coded for the swfupload.js file. In that case post_params: {} function will look like the following:

```
post_poarams: { 'your-variable-name-in-php-goes-here': 'value of this variable at this time goes here' },
```